# Component does not rerender when context changes

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-context

I've been playing around with the react context api and I'm just not getting why it's not working.

I have a component with a container that should show or hide depending on a valuer stored in context.

This is the component:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import ResultsContext from '../../context/results/resultsContext';

const ResultsPanelContainer = () => {
  const resultsContext = useContext(ResultsContext);
  const { showResults } = resultsContext;

  console.log('showResults in ResultsPanelConatiner: ', showResults);
  return (
    <div
      className='container-fluid panel'
      style={{ display: showResults ? 'block' : 'none' }}
    >
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col'>
            <h1 className='display-4'>Results.Panel.js</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResultsPanelContainer;
```

For completeness, the context is divided up into three sections, the call to the context itself, a 'state' file and a reducer. These are displayed below:

### resultsContext.js

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
const resultsContext = createContext();
export default resultsContext;
```

### ResultsState.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

// import axios from 'axios';
import ResultsContext from './resultsContext';
import ResultsReducer from './resultsReducer';

import { UPDATE_SHOW_RESULTS } from '../types';

const ResultsState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    showResults: false,
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ResultsReducer, initialState);

  const updateShowResults = (data) => {
    console.log('updateShowResults - ', data);
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_SHOW_RESULTS,
      payload: data,
    });
  };

  return (
    <ResultsContext.Provider
      value={{
        showResults: state.showResults,
        updateShowResults,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ResultsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ResultsState;
```

### resultsReducer.js

```
import { UPDATE_SHOW_RESULTS } from '../types';

export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case UPDATE_SHOW_RESULTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        showResults: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The change is triggered by a button click in a separate component and this *does* trigger an update in the context as shown when you log it to the console. However, the component is not rerendering.

I understand from reading various answers on here that changing context doesn't trigger a rerender of all child components in the same way that setState does. However, the component displaying this is calling the context directly so as far as I can see the rerender should take effect.

Am I missing something glaringly obvious?

Thanks in advance.
Stef

Answer (score 0):

Forget the above... I'm an idiot - wrapped the two separate parts of the app in two separate instances of ResultsState which weren't communicating. Did this:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <UsedDataState>
        <Header />
      </UsedDataState>
      <main>
        <ExportPanelContainer />
        <ResultsState>
          <SendQueryState>
            <OrQueryState>
              <AndQueryState>
                <QueryPanelContainer />
              </AndQueryState>
            </OrQueryState>
          </SendQueryState>
         </ResultsState>
         <ResultsState>
          <ResultsPanelContainer />
        </ResultsState>
      </main>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Instead of this:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <UsedDataState>
        <Header />
      </UsedDataState>
      <main>
        <ExportPanelContainer />
        <ResultsState>
          <SendQueryState>
            <OrQueryState>
              <AndQueryState>
                <QueryPanelContainer />
              </AndQueryState>
            </OrQueryState>
          </SendQueryState>
          <ResultsPanelContainer />
        </ResultsState>
      </main>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Hope this is useful for someone else...